# How to create a mock object based on an interface and set a read-only property?

Tags: tdd, rhino-mocks

I'm new to TDD. So any help would be appreciated. I'm using NUnit and Rhino mocks.
How can I set the ID value to 1 in my mock object?

I had a look at this: http://www.iamnotmyself.com/2008/06/26/RhinoMocksAndReadOnlyPropertyInjectionPart2.aspx
but the reflection doesn't seem to work against interfaces.

```
    public interface IBatchInfo
    {
        int ID { get;}
        Branches Branch { get; set; }
        string Description { get; set; }                                
    }

 [SetUp]
       public void PerFixtureSetup()
       {

           _mocks = new MockRepository();
           _testRepository = _mocks.StrictMock<IOLERepository>();

       }

    [Test]
            public void ItemsAreReturned()
            {
                IBatchInfo aBatchItem=  _mocks.Stub<IBatchInfo>();

                aBatchItem.ID = 1; //fails because ID is a readonly property
                aBatchItem.Branch = Branches.Edinburgh;


                List<IBatchInfo> list = new List<IBatchInfo>();

                list.Add( aBatchItem);

                Expect.Call(_testRepository.BatchListActive()).Return(list);
                _mocks.ReplayAll();

                BatchList bf = new BatchList(_testRepository, "usercreated", (IDBUpdateNotifier)DBUpdateNotifier.Instance);
                List<Batch> listofBatch = bf.Items;

                Assert.AreEqual(1, listofBatch.Count);
                Assert.AreEqual(1, listofBatch[0].ID);
                Assert.AreEqual( Branches.Edinburgh,listofBatch[0].Branch);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even better if using rhino mocks 3.5:

```
aBatch.Stub(x => x.ID).Return(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here http://haacked.com/archive/2007/05/04/setting-propertybehavior-on-all-properties-with-rhino-mocks.aspx.

Simple, instead of

```
aBatchItem.ID=1;
```

use:

```
SetupResult.For(aBatchItem.ID).Return(1);
```